# apple mach-o linker (id) error getting confused with this

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, xcodebuild

I just opened my project which was made in xcode 3.1.5 version in xcode 4.2 and am getting the following error's can anyone please help me in this regard.

1)

```
Ld /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app/ARecipeViewer normal i386
    cd /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Desktop/DevelopmentArea/ARecipe
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/lib -L/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/lib/gstreamer-0.10 -L/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/lib/pkgconfig -F/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Intermediates/ARecipeViewer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.build/Objects-normal/i386/ARecipeViewer.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lpocketsphinx -lsphinxbase -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30100 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -lsqlite3.0 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -liconv -lcv -lcxcore -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -o /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app/ARecipeViewer

ld: library not found for -lcv
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

2)

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app.dSYM /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app/ARecipeViewer
    cd /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Desktop/DevelopmentArea/ARecipe
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app/ARecipeViewer -o /Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app.dSYM

error: unable to open executable '/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app/ARecipeViewer'
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) As the first error says

```
ld: library not found for -lcv
```

It means your project needs a static library for `'cv'` and
either its is not there in your project or placed at some different location(if you are using it)

or

you are putting additional compiler flag in build settings(if you are not using the library in your code). following compiler flags in build settings.

```
-liconv -lcv -lcxcore
```

put cv library at right location.(so that it can be included in project).

2.) Second error may be because .app file is yet not created in derived data directory.
Go at path shown in error, i.e.. and verify whether .app file exist or not.

```
error: unable to open executable '/Users/hasmukh.mandavia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARecipeViewer-cdsqawgcznmakicuonkiinivjeed/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ARecipeViewer.app/ARecipeViewer'
```

Comment: search for 'Other linker flag' in build settings of your project. My mistake they are linker flag not compiler. Try by changing the DeriveData directory from XCode preferences. It will create build at new location. And see inside the .app file whether the ARecipeViewer file exists or not.

Comment: -lpocketsphinx 
-lsphinxbase     
I've added those two flags in my other linker flags still am getting the errors

Comment: these files -lcv and other are in frameworks. So look for what frameworks are added in your project. as log suggest -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -liconv -lcv -lcxcore -framework

Comment: Also make sure .pch file in your build settings should have same name as the file in your project. (for second error)